# interop Shapes.AddPicture creates incorrect dimension for image

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint, office-interop

I am using interop to create powerpoint presentation.i use Shapes.AddPicture to add images to slide.

```
Shapes.AddPicture(strImagePath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Convert.ToInt32(shape.Left), Convert.ToInt32(shape.Top), Convert.ToInt32(xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgwidth"].Value), Convert.ToInt32(xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgheight"].Value));//load new image to shape
```

i am passing imageheight as 127,
however final slide contains image with
             imageheight as 167.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand that the dimensions PPT uses are points (72 points to the inch)?  I'm guessing that you're expecting it to be pixels.  It won't be.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg:awesome......can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're expecting that PowerPoint uses pixels as its dimensions; it doesn't.  It uses points, 72 points to the inch.